# Need help understanding the meaning of a word and looking for other ways to express the idea

Tags: word-choice, expressions

Author:

> The report noted that “Personal causes of unemployment have
>   received, heretofore, a disproportionate amount of attention” (*citation*) and **called for policy measures reflecting an industrial approach** to the problem of unemployment.

I understand what that means in general, but what did they mean by "reflecting"? Alternate meaning of reflect, which is actually conveyed here, is "think deeply or carefully about". But I don't understand how it fits this context.

**What are other words/phrases that I can use instead in my version below?**

> The commission reported that individual deficiency, contrary to what many believed, was only a part of the problem and advised for policies that **took/reflected/considered** a more economic and industrial approach to unemployment.

Comment: *Reflecting* means, in this case, *showing*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [definition](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/reflect) of reflecting that you're looking for is

> verb
>
> If something **reflects** an attitude or situation, it shows that the
>   attitude or situation exists or it shows what it is like.
>
> *This conference with all of you here reflects the unity of our nation.
>   [VERB noun]*
>
> *Concern at the economic situation was reflected in the
>   government's budget. [VERB noun]*
>
> **Synonyms: show, reveal, express, display**

So, in your example, the report called for a more industrial, and less personal, approach to the problem of unemployment. The policies should **reflect** that that shift in focus.

Comment: Right. So it would be correct to rephrase it and say: "... called for policies that take an industrial approach to unemployment" ? If indeed the policies reflect that shift in focus, then for sure the policies are designed to take an industrial approach. Would you agree?

Comment: Well, it wouldn't be wrong. The original phrasing doesn't really add anything to that.